# How to share data between requests in Tornado Web

Tags: python, tornado

I have the following use case for my Tornado web server:

Upon POST requests entries can be made to the server, entries which will not be persisted to a file or database. Upon GET requests a process can be started or terminated.

Hence I need to share data between different requests in my `RequestHandler` implementation. What is the normal way to do so?

I had difficulties saving data to `self`, for instance `self.entry = "..."`. In another request the data was not present anymore.

The only working solution I've found is to store that in the application object:

```
    application = web.Application([
            (r'.*', MainHandler,
            ])
```

and

```
    def get(self):
         # ...
         self.application.entry = "..."
```

Is that the proper way? Also what about synchronization here, I mean this means access to shared data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suggest the following: Instead of a database access object pass an object which stores your data, for instance:

```
data = DataStore()

application = web.Application([
        (r'.*', MainHandler, dict(data = data),
        ])
```

with the following `RequestHandler` initialization method.

```
def initialize(self, data):
     self.data = data
```

You have to create the object before and pass it, otherwise it will be recreated every time a request is processed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tornado, but keep in mind that this probably won't work if your using more than one process.

Comment: @monkut More than one process for what, the server, the client?

Comment: Tornado is a single-process, single-threaded server... this will work.

Comment: Yes, if you keep it in signle-process mode this will work.  http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpserver.html

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/overview.html#overriding-requesthandler-methods) gives a way to do this :

```
class MyHandler(RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, database):
        self.database = database

    def get(self, username):
        ...

mydatabase = dict()

app = Application([
    (r'/user/(.*)', MyHandler, dict(database=mydatabase)),
    ])
```

Then you can save your object `mydatabase` to a file.

But I'm not sure this is the right way to achieve what you want regarding synchronization between requests.

Comment: I don't want to persist my data, I only want to save it during runtime. No database wanted or required here.

Comment: What I call `database` is just your data, you can use any type of data storage. It allows to save it during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memcached` for something like this.  However, you'll need to setup the memcached server.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached/

Comment: Isn't that a little bit overkill? I simply want to store 2 objects for the time of the running application.

Answer (score 1):

Application is the right object to store (semi-)persistent data. However, as suggested on other anwser, you should consider using some kind of database to store this data.

However, you should take care that wen a session (or transaction) doesn't finish properly (e.g. you get a POST but no GET to trigger the action), you should delete the session data so as not to have your webserver leak memory.

From my experience, I'd suggest using [Redis](http://redis.io) since it is easy to use and supports [key expiration](http://redis.io/commands/expire), a mechanism that comes handy when you need to manage session data.

Comment: Why should I use a database to store data which I don't want to persist? The data should only be available in the time of the running web server. If the web server crashes yes, the data should be invalidated. If the web server has to be restarted yes, the data should be invalidated.

Comment: I hear you. Application is definitely the way to go in this case. You may store your session data in any container you like in the Application instance. My remark was just that when/if your project grows in functionality, storing session data in a third-party store will probably be more and more useful. Think about application monitoring for instance : it could be great to retrieve/compute metrics on live session data from a store (as opposed to ther server itself) as it goes without disturbing/impacting your server performance.